# Determine all entire functions $f(z)$ such that $0$ is a removable singularity of $f(\frac{1}{z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

So I am not sure about the answer,
but what I did was write $f(z)$ in the series form i.e

$$f(z) = a_0 + ... + a_n z^n$$

then I consider $f(\frac{1}{z})$ - 
(and using the fact that in removable singularity principal part is zero)

I get that all $a_i$ except $a_0$ must be $0$!
So my answer is coming out to be $f(z) = c$, where $c$ is some constant!?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: why didn't you take negative powers in the series?

Comment: @ashishyadaveee11 It's given f(z) is entire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

You could also argue that if $0$ is a removable singularity of $f(1/z)$ then $f(1/z)$ is bounded near $z=0$, which in turn implies that $f$ is a bounded entire function (which is constant according to Liouville's theorem).