# All entire functions $f(z)$ such that 0 is removable singularity of $f(1/z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290911/determine-all-entire-functions-fz-such-that-0-is-a-removable-singularity-o). To this I would like to add does the function $$f(z)=e^{-z}$$ satisfies the requirement? This is an entire function and $0$ is removable singularity of $f(1/z)$ as $$\lim_{z\to0}e^{-1/z}=0$$
Also extending this, consider non-constant polynomial $g(z)$ the $e^{-g(z)}$ is entire function. $z=0$ is the pole of $g(1/z)$ so $$\lim_{z\to0}e^{g(-1/z)}=0$$

So all functions of the form $e^{-g(z)}$ satisfies these conditions.

Is this correct? Are there any other functions?

Comment: $\lim_{z\to0}e^{-1/z}$ doesn't exist. You're working with complex numbers, not with positive real numbers.

Comment: Along the imagionary axis, the limit of $e^{-\frac{1}{z}}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The singularity of $f(z)=e^{-1/z}$ as $z\to 0$ is not removable, but essential. In fact, $f(D(0,\epsilon)\setminus\{0\})$ is dense in $\Bbb C$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks.........